# Close all open Magit buffers when opening a new project

Tags: magit, project

When using Magit, the multitude of buffers can become a bit confusing when switching buffers. Therefore I prefer to have only one git-repository open in Magit. My current procedure of switching to another one requires to

- find magit's status buffer
- `C-u C-u q` to quit all of this git-repository's magit buffers
- `C-x g` for the new git-repository.

I would like to reduce this to just `C-x g` to open the new repo's status buffer. Is there some build-in trick in Magit to do this? Alternatively: is there a hook I could use to close all magit buffers before `magit-status`?

Comment: Say explicitly what you mean by switching to another "project". How are you doing that? Depending on what you mean by that, there may well be a relevant hook you can use, etc.

Comment: Sorry, "project" == git-repository == directory -> editing question.